# Can I somehow change the order of the tables to be displayed?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have three tables

```
<table class="table1">
   ...
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let data of datasource1">
      ...
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table2">
   ...
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let data of datasource2">
      ...
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table3">
   ...
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let data of datasource3">
      ...
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

and I want to somehow be in control of which table should be displayed in which order, i.e., first table3 then table1 then table2 (or some other order). How would I do that?

Comment: create a table component and set an input field for its data. Then pass the data accordingly to each component. If you need that dynamic, you can create function to pass that data

Comment: @Trouble That's a good idea. I will try to implement this! Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates can be created for each table and rendered in the required order based on a condition.

Create table templates:

```
<ng-template name="table1">
  <table class="table1">
   ...
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let data of datasource1">
      ...
      </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
</ng-template>

... similarly for table2, 3
```

I am assuming there is a variable `order` in your component.ts file which defines the order to use. And

1. If it's value is 1: order of tables is 1, 2, 3
2. If it's value is 2: order is 2, 3, 1
3. If it's value is 3: order is 3, 1, 2

So the html to render in required order could be one of the following as per your case

1.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="order === 1">
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="table1">
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="table2">
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="table3">
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="order === 2">
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="table2">
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="table3">
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="table1">
</ng-container>

Note: *ngIf needs to be updated with required condition
.... other conditions
```

2. 

```
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="order === 1 ? table1 : order === 2 ? table2 : table3">
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="order === 1 ? table2 : order === 2 ? table3 : table1">
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="order === 1 ? table3 : order === 2 ? table1 : table2">
```

Comment: That is also a nice idea. With this approach I would not need to create a separate table component

Comment: Consider accepting the answer which helped you so that others with similar usecase can benefit too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS, wrap the tables in a div and apply flex box - display: flex;
Assign tot each table an order - order: 0; order:1; and so on.